# precompile asset targets are 404 in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I want the assets directory outside of the app directory. So I moved it out.

- app

  - <s>assets</s>
- assets

And added the new folder to sprockets in `config/application.rb`.

```
config.assets.paths << root.join('assets')
```

Precompiling works fine, but I can't request assets in development mode.

```
Started GET "/stylesheets/application.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-27 23:32:50 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/application.css"):
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  ...
```